# app_name: LTR lang on left, RTL lang on right

Tags: android, xml, right-to-left

I would like to use both English and Hebrew in the app_name:  the English should be displayed all the way to the left, and the Hebrew should be displayed  all the way to the right.

Assigning a value to app_name which is the English name followed by the Hebrew will print the entire thing left-aligned or right-aligned, depending on if LTR or RTL.  This is acceptable, but ideally, I'd like the English portion to be left-aligned and the Hebrew portion to be right-aligned, not unlike MS Word allows you to do in a header/footer.  I've also tried to put in a tab ('\t'), but the result was the same.

```
<string name="app_name">Application Name שם אפליקציה</string>
```

The actual results are as I'd expect, but I'd like to do it differently.  Possible clue:  a friend of mine said I'd probably have to change the style, but couldn't offer more specific advice.

Comment: are you making both language string.xml files or not?

Comment: I didn't...would that help accomplish what I'd like?  The bulk of the words is in English.  Just the app_name and a couple more words on screen are not.  (I may decide to change that in the future, and give a language choice.)  The other Hebrew text is in a wrap_content TextView that looks fine.